# How to connect pascal dll to python?

Tags: python, dll, pascal

I have some functions in pascal dll. I need use this functions in my python code. How i can do this?

```
unit LwdCalcIntSLB;

interface

const
  Err_UnknownError=-1;
  Err_InvPallet=-2;
  Err_InvPalletFile=-3;
  Err_CntCreatePalletFile=-4;

function ExpPrepareDataLWDinit(wPath: PAnsiChar;                                 
     wBS, wDFD,                                                              
     wDDEV, wDTOOL: single): HResult; stdcall; external   'LwdCalcSLB.dll';  

function ExpFreeDataLWD: HRESULT; stdcall; external            'LwdCalcSLB.dll';

function ExpCalcWinkNormLWD (wRAT: single;                                       
     var wWINK: single): HRESULT; stdcall; external        'LwdCalcSLB.dll'; 

function ExpCalcRhobLWD (wRHOB: array of single;                                 
     var wRHU, wRHD: single): HRESULT; stdcall; external   'LwdCalcSLB.dll'; 

implementation


end.
```

I tryed ise ctypes library, but it is not good idea

Comment: This is most likely off-topic, and it is certainly too broad/vague in my opinion. See: [help/on-topic].

Comment: Maybe you should first explain why you think that ctypes is not a good idea.

Comment: I tried to use ctypes but some functions do not work.

Comment: Explain "do not work" in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stdcall, dlls and HResult are all windows related, include (USES) unit Windows.